# Masonry layout with css3 flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make kind of masonry layout of items using `display: flex;`

It's running good until my items has different sizes:

here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/2pL3j07x/1/

I want **small** items below **big** items to **wrap it around** (2 items in a 'row' below big item should easly fit but only 1 goes there)

Is it possible with css flex to do so?

Comment: Keep in mind that floating is NOT an option for this question.  The `<div>`s must go down from top to bottom, NOT LEFT TO RIGHT.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/wpzqo08p/ , anyway, it's not possible without js (and is hard for me to say this since I do love to do it using only CSS).

Comment: @coma, isn't your fiddle without JS?

Comment: @Godisgood, yes, but rotating everything and translating is ugly as hell and if you try adding more big squares it just breaks.

Comment: @coma, so you're saying that this layout is impossible without JS?

Comment: The layout is not possible with your current markup. Columns and rows only accept one child element. If you want 4 items under the big item instead of 2, you need to use another wrapper element for those 4 and also give it column/wrapping flex properties: http://jsfiddle.net/2pL3j07x/18/

Answer (score 4):

I know you don't want to use transforms, but this works exactly as described and actually has better browser support than flexbox does (although as far as the regularly updating browsers that's a less compelling argument than normal).

Regardless:

## [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pL3j07x/15/)

**What we're doing here:**

```
.flex-c {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scaleY(-1);
    transform-origin: left top;
}
```

**Setting the direction –** We're twisting it to go up to down by moving the left side of the container to the top, a one-quarter turn clockwise.

**Flipping the whole she-bang –** We're flipping the container on the Y-axis, so that the orientation is correct (apparent as `ltr` in this case)

```
.flex-c:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

**Fixing the float clearing stuff –** Good resource on that **[here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)**

```
.flex-i {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scaleY(-1);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    float: left;
}
```

**Reverting the flipping and twisting for individual items –** We want these to display correctly, so we untwist them with the `transform` rule to head the `.flex-i` rule.

So let's take a look at what's going on with the final result:

1. The big item is at the top left.
2. Items are displayed in columns.
3. The columns are filled from top to bottom.
4. The growth is infinitely expansible.

Some downsides:

1. Your vertices are flipped for layout on this container.  You can mitigate this somewhat by keeping it in a third container for wrap if you don't mind extra markup *(I personally do, but to each their own).*
2. This is going to fail miserably on older browsers – but so is your flexbox solution, so kind of a wash.

Hope this helps!

## Edit:

So the comments raised the rather obvious question *"What if we want more than one big element in this layout?"*

Perfectly reasonable, and the solution as presented is going to leave some rather ugly gaps, granted.  Unfortunately, if you need a pure content fill for those, you'll need to get much more creative and use either a JavaScript layout system (boo, slow, nasty, hard-to-maintain) or do something that several other masonry layouts have had to do before: **tuckpointing**

We're going to shim our empty spaces with dummy items.  These can be pre-selected images, tiles, anything that's going to add a splash of flair in place of actual content without distracting from the content.

Here's how we do it:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pL3j07x/22/)**

**Update the `.flex-c` container to hide its overflow**

```
.flex-c {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scaleY(-1);
    transform-origin: left top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Add an easily disguised shim pseudo-element**

```
.flex-i:not(.big):after {
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 110px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

*ALTERNATIVELY: You can do this in a way that's less CSS3-fancy but has better support*

```
.flex-i:after {
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 110px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
}
.flex-i.big:after {
    display: none;
}
```

What this does in terms of the fiddle is creates a little pink box that pops out of the right side of each one of those content items.  If there's a box there already, it gets covered up.  If it's missing, we show the dummy box.  Super simple.

Comment: I really like this solution, but look at what happens when I add another `.big`.  http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/2pL3j07x/17/ It still skips the second div in a row.  Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Well, if we're talking actual items, no.  There's no easy solution for that one.  _However..._ you can do something where you do some "tuckpointing" in your masonry layout, so-to-speak.  Something like this here: http://jsfiddle.net/2pL3j07x/19/

Comment: An even better tuckpointing solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/2pL3j07x/20/, I'll add this one to the original answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2pL3j07x/25/ - please consider this one. I've just doubled entire container and expected result would be 2 sets of items one below another, but they overlay each other.

Answer (score 2):

I think for what you are tryig to do, it would be easier using `float:left;` instead of the `flex` property.  I made an updated

### [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2pL3j07x/8/)

```css
.flex-c {
    display: block;
    height: 450px;
    width: auto;
}

.flex-i {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.big {
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    float:left;
}

.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="flex-c">
        <div class="flex-i big"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need layout items to show from top to down and then to next column. When you float they go left right and then down.

Comment: Why will floating not work for you?  Please explain what you are trying to do in detail.  Would you like a layout like [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-stacked-columns-pixels.htm)?

Comment: I've got horizontal layout that expand from left to right (so newest posts are on left and old are on right). Thats why they cant be like this. It should be something like float: top-left; connected with flex columns

Comment: No such thing as `float:top-left`. I'm working on something, though.

Comment: I can't seem to figure this out.  Can't find anything on the web, either.  Anyone else know the answer to this?