# Layout tiles with variable sizes without tables, filling available space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float, grid-layout

I want to create a page layout that *resembles* the following

```
############  #####  #####  #####
############  #####  #####  #####
############  #####  #####  #####
############ 
############  #####  ############
############  #####  ############
############  #####  ############
                     ############
#####  ############  ############
#####  ############  ############
#####  ############  ############
#####  
#####  #####  ############  #####
#####  #####  ############  #####
#####  #####  ############  #####
```

**Not that layout exactly**, that is just an example.  The idea is 1x1 tiles mixed with 1x2, 2x1, and 2x2 tiles, with the freedom to mix and match to my heart's content.  *That means filling available space.*

I can do it easy enough with tables.  But then it is not responsive.  I tried using `float: left` but there is a rule: a floated item will not appear left of a previously floated item.  Which means when I try to create the above layout, I get holes, like so:

```
############  #####  #####  #####
############  #####  #####  #####
############  #####  #####  #####
############ 
############  #####  ############
############  #####  ############
############  #####  ############
                     ############
                     ############
                     ############
                     ############

#####  ############  #####   
#####  ############  #####    
#####  ############  #####  
#####
#####  ############  #####
#####  ############  #####
#####  ############  #####
```

What is the correct, modern, responsive way of doing something like what I am trying to do?

Comment: May want to look at questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435502/masonry-layout-with-css3-flex/26852325

Comment: Interesting, but confusing.  And definitely does not do what I ultimately want, which is to have the content auto-adjust as I make my browser window bigger.

Comment: You could make that work as dynamically sized just by changing the unit for the layout.  Instead of `px` use something like `vh`, `vw` or `%`

Comment: I want fixed size images, I just want the number of columns to grow and shrink as the viewport changes.

Comment: Have you tried with row span ,column span and display:inline block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am trying to do can not be done using float:left.  But it can be done using JavaScript, and there is a library already out there which is easy to integrate that works great:

http://packery.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do two different things. One, to have fluid columns. Two, to increase or decrease the number of columns depending on the screen size.

You can achieve fluid columns by using percentages or min-width/max-width instead of a pixel value. Once you have that, you can add media queries to change the layout depending on the size of the viewer's browser. It would be up to you where you want to set up the breakpoints.

Comment: The key to what I'm trying to do is fill available space with a fluid layout of fixed-sized items of varying sizes.