# CSS and DIV 3 columns with " TILES "

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a website that would look like this :

[image]

So each cell has a size based on content.  I'm stuck with the CSS part of it any idea on how I could do this ?

For a real example of what I'm trying to do :

http://yourquestions.mcdonalds.ca/

Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Lots of answers on this already.  Search "masonry layout."  Here's one I answered awhile back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435502/masonry-layout-with-css3-flex/26852325#26852325

Comment: Since I'm not doing a lot of web dev, it's kind of hard to find things sometimes.  Masonry is the answer (at least for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible ways around this problem.

1. Use a jQuery API which does it for you ([Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is a good start).
2. Split your data into three sections (See working example)

```css
table {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
}
table.left tr td {
  background-color: red;
}

table.middle tr td {
  background-color: blue;
}

table.right tr td {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="left">
<tr>
  <td style="height:10em">
 <div>Left 1</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
 <div style="height:2em">Left 2</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
 <div style="height:3em"> Left 3</div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="middle">
<tr>
  <td>
 <div style="height:1em">Middle 1</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
 <div style="height:4em">Middle 2</div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
   <div style="height:7em">Middle 3</div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="right">
  <tr>
 <td>
   <div style="height:5em">Right 1</div>
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>
   <div style="height:5em">Right 2</div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
  <div style="height:8em">Right 3</div>
 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support browsers under ie10 you can do this natively in CSS. Just give your container a column style...

```
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}

<ul>
     <li>List Item</li>
     <li>List Item</li>
     <li>List Item</li>
     <li>List Item</li>
     <li>List Item</li>
     <li>List Item</li>
     <li>List Item</li>
     <li>List Item</li>
</ul>
```

You can also specify how much room is in-between each column. See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp for more info