# Arrange a few divs

Tags: html, css

I have a few divs to arrange but im stuck. It should look like this

[image]

Im working on it for a couple of hours and it wont get better.
Here is the code i wrote so far. I thinks there is an easy solution for a pro.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<style type="text/css">

 
#wrapper {
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
 
#content_3 {
float: left;
background: #bbb;
width: 200px;
}
 
#content_2 {
float: left;
width: 200px;
background: #aaa;
}
 
 
#content_4 {
float: right;
width: 200px;
background: #ddd;
}
 
#content_1 {
float:left;
width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #eee;
}

</style>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="wrapper">
<div>
  <div id="content_1">content_1</div>
     <div id="content_2">content_2</div>
     <div id="content_3">content_3</div>
</div>

     <div id="content_4">content_4</div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help?

[Wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPuYB.jpg)

Both solution worked for me fine but the content of DIV 2 is increasing and so content 3 and 4 are moving down. How can i fix this? Conten_3 and 4 should stay right under content_1

Comment: Your doctype is one that should not be used for new web pages since 1999. Update that to the current one which is required: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Masonry layout with css3 flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435502/masonry-layout-with-css3-flex) [Search on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=masonry+layout) or Google for "masonry layout" and find a multitude of same answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I advice to go with [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), much easier :

You first divide the layout in 2 columns (`div1,div2,div3` in the first and `div4` in the second). Then in the first column you simply make the first div to be `width:100%` and use **wrap** to make the 2 remaining go to the next row.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.first {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#content_1 {
  background: #bbb;
  width: 100%;
}

#content_2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: #aaa;
}

#content_4 {
  flex: 1;
  background: #ddd;
}

#content_3 {
  flex: 1;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <div id="content_1">content_1</div>
    <div id="content_2">content_2</div>
    <div id="content_3">content_3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content_4">content_4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Teratek i added more explanation to the answer ;) and i highly advice you to read more about flexbox layout and your life will be easier :) of course this is not the only way you will get more answer using float,inline-block, grid, etc ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another alternative with CSS grid. Hope, it helps :)

We divide wrapper in 3 columns giving each column fraction 1. Then for each content we just mention the row and column and if we need to combine to rows or column we use span as shown.

Advantage: You don't need to worry about height and width, you can make use of fractions to divide them.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#wrapper * {
  text-align: center;
}

#content_1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background: red;
}

#content_2 {
  background: #aaa;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

#content_3 {
  background: #bbb;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

#content_4 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content_1">content_1</div>
  <div id="content_2">content_2</div>
  <div id="content_3">content_3</div>
  <div id="content_4">content_4</div>
</div>
```